# How should I divide my code using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have searched the web and found only styling code posts. I want to write site using Code Igniter and I wonder how should I maintain my code.

For example:

Should I use one class for static pages and methods for each page or separate file for every static page. Should I use the same file to load dynamic pages or different one?

Can I use some common code and include it automatically to every class?

How can I have lets say header_view footer_view etc and then just load->view('whatever') and footer, header and other files would load automatically. Maybe there is better way to do that?

In generall what are the best practices when coding using CodeIgniter.

Comment: You mean you write site using PHP  not CodeIgniter, You use the CodeIgniter PHP framework that helps pave the way to rapid application development

Comment: @RPM I know. It was just a mental shortcut. Please don't post if you have nothing to say regarding the topic.

Comment: It sounds like you have several questions and are just generally uncertain how to structure your project. My advice would be to follow this tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/ and also look at some existing projects built with Codeigniter on Github.

Comment: what u want to know exactly. After i saw u r question this is what i got u want to know how to develop an application with codeIgniter. How to divide your code structure.Am i right

Answer (score 0):

You can use one single class for static pages (and use one method for each page).

You can use the same one to load dynamic pages, but it is better IMO to load them with a separate class. It will be easier to maintain later.

Using common code: You can always override the CI_Controller with your own, and instantiating controllers from yours. [Here is an example](http://www.lizjamieson.co.uk/394/getting-started-with-codeigniter-6/) about how to do it.

You can load multiple views in a single controller function. A view doesn't have to be a full html document. You can also load the same view multiple times (for example in a loop).

Best practices: CodeIgniter is an MVC framework. IMO, MVC is a best practice. Always use the framework's documented features if they are suitable for what you want to achieve ([CodeIgniter's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) is very good. That link is momentarily offline, so please try [this one](http://userguides.ellislab.com/codeigniter/)).

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is a MVC based framework, MVC is basically used for organizing your code, so at last its up to you how you are going to use it so ease you on the long term.
Basically when I design large projects in codeigniter I tried to to make unit of functionality at one place lets take example of any simple users, messages based project.

I tried to make functionality by grouping main topics, in this example user will be a controller, in that controller there will be methods like login, register, edit, listing, forgot_password now I'll create single model with all the methods which will give data for these above methods. by using this methods our urls will be also meaningfull like /user/login, /user/register etc

like that if its messages I will create controller message and add all related methods in it so that my related functionality will be in a single group.

as far as the question of static pages you can also group them in a single controller if they can be a part of group.

you can also use codeigniter's caching technique for static pages so that your pages will load faster